# Getting error "Value cannot be null.Parameter name: type" when implementing a spam filter for UGC in .NET

Tags: content-delivery, ugc

I have added the Sample .NET spam filter implementation code inside the class in "App_Code" folder

I have also updated the web.config file with below keys.

```
Comment.SpamFilter.Assembly
Comment.SpamFilter.Implementation
Comment.SpamFilter.Exclude1
```

I am able to submit/ view the Comments when I remove the above keys from web.config file.

Please suggest.

```
<add key="Comment.SpamFilter.Assembly" value="namespace name" />
<add key="Comment.SpamFilter.Implementation" value="namespace name.WordsSpamFilter" />
<add key="Comment.SpamFilter.Exclude1" value="poker" />

[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: type]
   Tridion.ContentDelivery.UGC.Web.Utilities.UGCConfigurationLoader..ctor() +293
   Tridion.ContentDelivery.UGC.Web.Utilities.UGCConfigurationLoader..cctor() +28

[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Tridion.ContentDelivery.UGC.Web.Utilities.UGCConfigurationLoader' threw an exception.]
   Tridion.ContentDelivery.UGC.WebService.WebServiceHelper.PostComment(String itemUri, String username, String email, String content) +422
   Tridion.ContentDelivery.UGC.Web.UI.ManageComments.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +505
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +246
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +315
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +48
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +246
   System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +40
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5274
```

Comment: Given that the error is thrown by `UGCConfigurationLoader` it would be helpful to post the sections you added to web.config - it does seem to be related to it.

Comment: Updated the question with config enteries

Comment: Can you compile your code and put it inside a DLL? That DLL should in turn be added to the bin folder.

Comment: I have already compiled it and respective dll is in bin folder. I have created App_Code folder in my solution where I have inserted the spam filter code in a class. Then I have build my project and put the dll in the bin folder but after inserting above keys in the web.config I get the above error. Thanks

Comment: @Meenakshi have you come to a solution for this issue? Maybe you can provide an update with either the solution or more information so we can close this question with a valid answer? In reading through your question again, I could come up with this one btw. maybe it is of some help? http://serverfault.com/questions/393721/what-is-the-correct-way-to-configure-a-tridion-ugc-spam-filter-net

Answer (score 2):

I added the class called "WordsSpamFilter" which inherits the SpamFilter class in App_Code folder.

The issue resolved when I change the "Build Action" property of my class from "Content" to "Compile".

Thanks
Meenakshi